# determining if a regime of virtual memory is readable

Tags: c, windows, performance, virtual-memory

let's say I want to examine the entire 4GB address space of my `win32` user-mode app.
since trying to read directly from random places throws an `access violation` , I was thinking to check first for readability of each page:

```
char* p = 0x00000000;
while (p < 0xf0000000 ) 
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    VirtualQuery ( p , & mbi , 100) ;
    if (!(  mbi.Protect | PAGE_NOACCESS ) )        
         char tmp = *p;
    p = p + PAGE_SIZE;


}
```

is there any other way, more efficient to just that?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, just call VirtualAlloc() with the 1st argument set to NULL.

Comment: Please note that I don't want to allocate anything, just to examine the memory.

Comment: What exactly is the point of that?  What are you doing to ensure that another thread in the process isn't allocating memory?

Comment: it is for a purely educational purpose. let's say I want to look for some binary sequence in my VM for instance, how should I do it?

Comment: Yes, VirtualQuery.  Not just the first one it returns, all of them.  Of course you don't care much about efficiency, you'll trip lots of page faults.

Comment: so how can I locate the allocated pages to focus on?

Comment: VirtualQuery will tell you whether a range of pages is allocated or not, and how long it is.  Just start with page zero and iterate through all the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You must check for state == MEM_COMMIT and protection != PAGE_NOACCESS to avoid invalid memory regions.  This code will list the beginning and end address of each valid memory region:

```cpp
HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

while (VirtualQuery(addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{
    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "base : 0x" << std::hex << mbi.BaseAddress << " end : 0x" << std::hex << (uintptr_t)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize << "\n";
    }
    addr += mbi.RegionSize;
}
```